# List item is not splitting data into two separate columns jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**Problem**

I am trying to split some returned data into two separate columns as it displays only as a single column of data by default.

The script is as follows:

```js
console.log(prop.toUpperCase() + ': ', obj[prop]);

const markup = `<li class="list-group-item">${(prop.toUpperCase() + ': ', obj[prop])}</li>`;
                        
document.getElementById("result-list").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
```

```css
ul {
color: white;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul id="result-list" class="list-group"></ul>
```

Which gives the following in the console:

```js
DESCRIPTION:  The Harvester
TYPE:  Restaurant
DESCRIPTION:  McDonalds
TYPE:  Fast food
etc etc...
```

However, in the front end I get:

```js
The Harvester
Restaurant
McDonalds
Fast food
etc etc...
```

I would like to maintain the first column (effectively) shown by the console, which would have a DESCRIPTION heading (and hold all descriptions beneath), with the second column heading set as TYPE, which would hold all types beneath, e.g.

[image]

**What I've tried**

I've tried the following in my css, as well as a few other variations, but they don't seem to work...

```css
ul {
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: If you want tabular output, why not use a `<table>`?

Comment: Hi @Barmar. Thanks for the suggestion, are you able to show how you would get a table working for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an issue in this part `` const markup = `<li class="list-group-item">${(prop.toUpperCase() + ': ', obj[prop])}</li>`; `` Please change it to `` markup += `<li class="list-group-item">${(prop.toUpperCase() + ': '+obj[prop])}</li>` ``

According to my understanding, my full code is as follow:

```
let data = [
  {"dscripiton": "The Harvester", "type":"Restaurant"}, 
  {"dscripiton": "McDonalds", "type":"Fast food"},
  {"dscripiton": "ok", "type":"ok?"}
]
var markup = "";
data.forEach((obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((prop) => {
        console.log(prop.toUpperCase() + ': ', obj[prop]);
    markup += `<li class="list-group-item">${(prop.toUpperCase() + ': '+obj[prop])}</li>`;
  });
});


                        
document.getElementById("result-list").insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', markup);
```

Comment: In my instance, this returned duplicates of every Type and Description in a single column. Changing 'afterend' to 'beforeend' meant it was logged in table rows, as requested, but again only one column - not two. With the 'afterend' you suggested it logged the data as recurring bullet points - which isn't the brief...

Comment: I should add, Description and type are now showing... this is how it looks my side...

Comment: ```
if(typeof(obj[prop]) == "object"){
    iterateObject(obj[prop]);
        } else {
            var markup = "";
                Object.keys(obj).forEach((prop) => {    
                    if(prop == "Description" || prop == "Type") {
                        console.log(prop.toUpperCase() + ': ', obj[prop]);
                        markup += `<li class="list-group-item">${(prop.toUpperCase() + ': '+obj[prop])}</li>`;
                    }
    });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you've trid. `What I've tried`

```
let data = [
  {"dscripiton": "The Harvester", "type":"Restaurant"}, 
  {"dscripiton": "McDonalds", "type":"Fast food"},
  {"dscripiton": "etc etc", "type":"etc etc"}
]

data.forEach((obj) => {
  let el = document.createElement('li');
  el.className = "list-group-item";
  
  let arr = [];
  for(prop in obj) {
    el.innerHTML += `<span style="margin-left: 30px">${obj[prop]}</span>`;
  }
  console.log(el)
    document.getElementById("result-list").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', el.outerHTML);
  
});
```

Comment: This just spits results all over my screen, in no particular order...

Answer (score 0):

Use a table rather than a list.

```js
const data = [
    {description: "McDonalds", type: "Fast Food"},
    {description: "The Harvester", type: "Restaurant"}
];

data.forEach(({description, type}) => {
  const markup = `<tr class="list-group-item"><td>${description.toUpperCase()}</td><td>${type}</td></th>`;
  document.getElementById("result-table-body").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
});
```

```css
#result-table td, #result-table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="result-table" class="list-group">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Type</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="result-table-body">
  </tbody>
</table>
```